# Getting list of all tasks from celery backend

Tags: python, celery

I've got a celery application which is using a backend to store the results of completed tasks.

While the tasks are queued/running, I can get information about them, but after they've completed, how can I get a list of all task IDs from the result backend?

I'd like to do this from within a python application, and in a way that doesn't depend on a specific backend (e.g. I might want to switch between filesystem and MySQL as a result store in future).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution is to store information about tasks which were finished in db. First of all it will be easy for processing.
Here is just an example with `SQLite`. Table for our tasks:

```
# You can add specific columns for args, kwargs etc.
# it is just an example 
CREATE TABLE celery_tasks (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    "task_id" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "task_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "state" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "created" TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

Our celery application `tasks.py`:

```
import celery
from celery.signals import task_postrun
from celery.task import Task
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime


@task_postrun.connect()
def task_postrun(signal=None, sender=None, task_id=None, task=None,
                 args=None, kwargs=None, retval=None, state=None):
    # For example we don't want to store info about specific tasks 
    ignored_tasks = ('tasks.ignore_task', )

    if task.name not in ignored_tasks:
        # write info about a finished task into SQLite
        conn = sqlite3.connect('db')
        conn.execute(
            'INSERT INTO celery_tasks (task_id, task_name, state, created) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
            (task_id, task.name, state, datetime.now())
        )

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()


app = celery.Celery(
   'tasks',
   broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',
   backend='redis://localhost:6379/0',
)


@app.task
def success_task():
    pass


@app.task
def failure_task():
    raise Exception('something wrong')


@app.task
def ignore_task():
    """
    Example of the task that we want to ignore for SQLite.
    """
    pass
```

`run_tasks.py`:

```
from tasks import success_task, failure_task, ignore_task

success_task.delay()
failure_task.delay()
ignore_task.delay()
```

So, after this you can use regular SQL queries to get any information about finished tasks in any place of the code.(`SELECT * FROM celery_tasks WHERE created ... AND ...`)

Also you can clear the table from time to time. 
I think using db is a good solution for this purpose.

**One more way.**

You can configure [CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#database-backend-settings) setting. In this case `celery` will create `celery_tasksetmeta`, `celery_taskmeta` tables. Task data will be actualized automatically:

```
app = Celery(
    'app_name',
    broker='CELERY_BROKER_URL...',
    backend='db+mysql://credentials...',
)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.from_url('redis://localhost:6379/0')
>>> r.keys()
[b'celery-task-meta-e939ee1b-b777-48f2-854d-6548b1f1a096']
```

https://redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html#keys